# Exception while trying to deploy Maven build JAR to github package registry

Tags: java, maven, github, github-package-registry

I am trying to deploy the Maven build JAR to Github Package Registry.

I am getting exception when I execute `mvn deploy` command.

I am using a simple Maven project which I want to create a component JAR and store in Github Package Registry.

The build is successful I now want to deploy this artifact to registry.

I have added the below in `~./m2/settings.xml`.

Added a `repository` element under `repositories` in `profile`.

```
    <repository>
          <id>github</id>
          <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/swastikaa-in</url>
        </repository>
 <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>swastikaa</username>
      <password>my personal token from github</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

Also, I have added the below in Maven project's `pom.xml`:

```
 <distributionManagement>
   <repository>
     <id>github</id>
     <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
     <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/swastikaa-in/math</url>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

**Expected**:
Deployment to be successful , build artifact is deployed to Github package registry.

**Actual**:
Exception as below:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException:
  Could not transfer metadata com.redjohn.tools:math:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/swastikaa-in/math):
  Failed to transfer file https://maven.pkg.github.com/swastikaa-in/math/com/redjohn/tools/math/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  with status code 400

Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException:
  Failed to transfer file https://maven.pkg.github.com/swastikaa-in/math/com/redjohn/tools/math/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
  with status code 400
```

Can someone help me in resolving the issue.

I have followed the instructions provided in the below link:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-package-registry

Comment: please list the permissions in your token. You might be missing package related permissions

Comment: I am getting the same error. @rasagulla in, have you managed to find any solution to this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found that snapshot versions don't work well. If you deploy a non snapshot version, it should work.

Comment: Snapshot versions do not work. Deploy works, but unable to download the artefact.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `settings.xml` file, `<url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY</url>` you need to make use that `OWNER` is replaced with your github `username` and `REPOSITORY` is replaced with the name of your project repository in github.